# How does the compiler choose which value to give auto?

Tags: c++, int, double, auto

First off, I am aware that this is an extremely simple question.  I'm just looking for a technical explanation as to why the compiler decides to make the following variable with an auto type specifier the type double over int:

```
int value1 = 5;
double value2 = 2.2;
auto value3 = value1 * value2;
```

I know that the compiler will derive the double type for value3 from the initialized value, but why exactly is that?

Comment: `int * double` is `double`. I don't know about you, but I don't expect `std::cout << (3 * 1.5);` to print 4.

Comment: "but why exactly is that?" - because the C++ specification says so. And it says so because it's probably the most meaningful way to define the behavior.

Comment: Look up c++ widening conversion if you want chapter and verse eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841839/difference-between-widening-and-narrowing-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`auto` variable types are defined in terms of template type deduction.  Like this:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T t);

f(value1 * value2);  // will call f<double>()
```

The reason `value1 * value2` gives `double` rather than `int` is because the arithmetic conversion rules allow turning `int` into `double` (the reverse is an implicit conversion also but not an arithmetic conversion).  When you use operators on built-in types, "the usual arithmetic conversions are applied".

Here's the rule found in section 5 (Expressions) of the Standard:

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way.  The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result.This pattern is called the *usual arithmetic conversions*, which are defined as follows:
>
> - If  either  operand  is  of  scoped  enumeration  type,  no  conversions  are  performed;  if  the  other operand does not have the same type, the expression is ill-formed.
> - If either operand is of type `long double`, the other shall be converted to `long double`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `double`, the other shall be converted to `double`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `float`, the other shall be converted to `float`.
> - Otherwise, the integral promotions shall be performed on both operands.

Answer (score 2):

Because when multiplying an `int` by a `double` you get a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ compilers always promote basic numeric types to the most general type included in an expression. So, any expression involving two `int` values yields an `int`, but if either of the operands is `double`, then the expression value will also be `double`.